# Use of internal direct links inside a navigation menu

Tags: usability, menu

I have got an navigation menu like this example:

[image]

the black arrows symbolise links from main menu to submenu pages. This pages contain a page to subject specific forms. I want to collect all the forms on an extra form page so all subject ordered forms link to this side (red arrows). So by clicking one of the "form-sublinks" the user gets to the general form side.

Is that a feasible way of implementation in reference to usability?
(All forms on a page makes it easy to update the stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research shows adding multiple navigation paths can effect the usability in a positive way.

For example: On an e-commerce site, if your looking for a dishwasher, would you look under 'white goods' or 'kitchen appliances'?

Both right?

Placing it under both categories can increase the user experience.

In your case it's pretty much the same. Your user will probably look for the form under 'subject X' or 'extra'.

Just make sure there is a distinct difference between the three forms. If the user clicked 'forms to subject 2' and enters a page that first has forms to subject 1 and a little further down forms to subject 2, there will be confusion and a possibility users will fill out the wrong form.

Comment: on the mainform page there will be links to all PDF-forms. The PDFs would be organized into sections. Is that also a good way?

Comment: @kimliv Ah. So those forms are for printing. To improve UX I would send unique parameters with the url when the user is navigating from 'forms to subject X' to 'forms'. This way you can highlight the right section to draw users' attention.